# Greatest $n$ such that $2^n$ divides divides $K$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I don't have any idea how to even begin with this..

> Let $K$ be the product of all factors $(b-a)$ (not necessarily distinct) where $a$ and $b$ are integers satisfying $1\le a < b \le 20$. Find the greatest positive integer $n$ such that $2^n$ divides $K$.

Can someone give a lead? A solution is also welcome...

Comment: $K = 19^1 \cdot 18^2 \cdot 17^3 \cdot \cdots$

Comment: To start with, how many pairs $(a,b)$ with $b-a$ divisible by $2$? (I get $90.$) Then, how many divisible by $4$? by $ 8$? by $ 16$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many of those factors $b-a$ are divisible by $2$? That means $a$ and $b$ are both odd or both even, so the number is $\binom{10}2+\binom{10}2=90.$

How many are divisible by $4$? Take both $a$ and $b$ from one of the sets $\{1,5,9,13,17\}$ or $\{2,6,10,14,18\}$ or $\{3,7,11,15,19\}$ or $\{4,8,12,16,20\},$ so the number is $4\cdot\binom52=40.$

How many are divisible by $8$? Pick $a$ and $b$ from one of the sets $\{1,9,17\}$ or $\{2,10,18\}$ or $\{3,11,19\}$ or $\{4,12,20\}$ or $\{5,13\}$ or $\{6,14\}$ or $\{7,15\}$ or $\{8,16\},$ so the number is $4\cdot\binom32+4\cdot\binom22=16.$

There are $4$ factors divisible by $16$ and none divisible by $32,$ so the final answer is $90+40+16+4=\boxed{150}.$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:  In general, there are $20-n$ pairs of integers $(a, b)$ that differ by $n$ because we can let $b$ be any integer from $n+1$ to $20$ and set $a$ equal to $b-n$. Thus, the product is $(1^{19})(2^{18})\cdots(19^1)$ (or alternatively, $19! \cdot 18! \cdots 1!$.).

When we count the number of factors of $2$, we have $4$ groups, factors that are divisible by $2$ at least **once, twice, three times and four times**. For those numbers, take the exponent corresponding to each one of them, add them case by case and then totally add them. Hope it helps.